# Getting an the name of an item and getting the string value returns gibberish

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

I want to get the player whos name matches the name of the block which was placed and updated this players gamemode to survival. But this just gives me gibberish in the console:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlace(BlockPlaceEvent blockPlaceEvent){
    //Player ded = Bukkit.getPlayer(String.valueOf(blockPlaceEvent.getItemInHand().displayName()));- not important
    //gives just the item name
    blockPlaceEvent.getPlayer().sendMessage(blockPlaceEvent.getItemInHand().displayName());
    //gibberish
    System.out.println(Bukkit.getPlayer(String.valueOf(blockPlaceEvent.getItemInHand().displayName())));


}
```

```
[19:15:09 INFO]: [Immortality] [STDOUT] TranslatableComponentImpl{key="chat.square_brackets", args=[TextComponentImpl{content="", style=StyleImpl{obfuscated=not_set, bold=not_set, strikethrough=not_set, underlined=not_set, italic=true, color=null, clickEvent=null, hoverEvent=null, insertion=null, font=null}, children=[TextComponentImpl{content="Windows_Paride", style=StyleImpl{obfuscated=not_set, bold=not_set, strikethrough=not_set, underlined=not_set, italic=not_set, color=null, clickEvent=null, hoverEvent=null, insertion=null, font=null}, children=[]}]}], style=StyleImpl{obfuscated=not_set, bold=not_set, strikethrough=not_set, underlined=not_set, italic=not_set, color=NamedTextColor{name="yellow", value="#ffff55"}, clickEvent=null, hoverEvent=HoverEvent{action=show_item, value=ShowItem{item=KeyImpl{namespace="minecraft", value="player_head"}, count=1, nbt={SkullOwner:{Id:[I;1311740293,1907444130,-1719123357,-1000482567],Name:"Windows_Paride",Properties:{textures:[{Signature:"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",Value:"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"}]}},Unbreakable:1b,display:{Name:'{"text":"Windows_Paride"}'}}}}, insertion=null, font=null}, children=[]}
```

I tried doing ComponentLike etc but it returned null when I did that.

Comment: ```Bukkit.getPlayer()``` returns a ```Player``` object. So the "gibberish" is actually the ```Player``` instance information. What do you exactly want to print here?

Comment: just the name of the player so for example if my mc name is abla I would like to be given the output abla. Also I cant just do Bukkit.getPlayer(...).setGamemode as of now

Comment: it just returns null cause it tried to do that for the instance information

Comment: Bukkit.getPlayer(blockPlaceEvent.getItemInHand().displayName()); returns an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments you're trying to get h the name of the player.

Refer https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/entity/Player.html#getName() from the documentation.

First get the Player object and then fetch the name from the player object.

```
Player player = Bukkit.getPlayer(String.valueOf(blockPlaceEvent.getItemInHand().displayName()));

player.getName();
```

Comment: how would I set the gamemode of that player? cause when I do that: `Player ded = Bukkit.getPlayer(String.valueOf(blockPlaceEvent.getItemInHand().displayName()));
        assert ded != null;
        ded.setGameMode(GameMode.SURVIVAL);`
then it doesnt work. It says: ded is null, even though it isnt

Comment: Again - the player is attached to the blockPlaceEvent, `blockPlaceEvent.getPlayer()`

Comment: I dont want the player who placed the block

Comment: I want to get the player whos name matches the name of the block which was placed and updated this players gamemode to survival

Answer (score 1):

As the received [BlockPlaceEvent](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/event/block/BlockPlaceEvent.html#%3Cinit%3E(org.bukkit.block.Block,org.bukkit.block.BlockState,org.bukkit.block.Block,org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack,org.bukkit.entity.Player,boolean,org.bukkit.inventory.EquipmentSlot)) already contains a reference to the [Player](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/entity/Player.html) and the later has a property called [name](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/entity/Player.html#getName()) (or even [displayName](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/entity/Player.html#getDisplayName())), it should be as easy as:

```java
@EventHandler
public void onPlace(BlockPlaceEvent blockPlaceEvent){
  blockPlaceEvent.getPlayer()
    .sendMessage(blockPlaceEvent.getItemInHand().displayName());
  System.out.println(blockPlaceEvent.getPlayer().getName());
}
```

Comment: I dont want to get the name of the player who placed the block but the player of the name of the item that the player has placed down